# How can I make this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a Dropdownlist that I fill with all consultants.

This is my entities I am using for this LINQ query:

[image]

What I want to do is to get all consultants ids that have a goalcard with Complete_date set. I have no idea how to do this.

Right now I have this following LINQ query to get all consultants ids.

```
public List<Consultant> GetAllConsultantsByID()
{
    var allConsultants = from id in db.Consultant
                         select id;
    return allConsultants.ToList();
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Update:

This is how I have to use my Linq method in my Get Action Method:

```
var consultants = repository.GetAllConsultantsByID();
model.Consultants = new SelectList(consultants, "Id", "Name");
```

Comment: Right, I have seen that you want a full `Consultant` object a bit late, edited my answer to reflect that too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Consultant.GoalCard` navigation property and the [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338.aspx) extension method:

```
var query = from con in db.Consultant
            where con.GoalCard.Any(card => card.Completed_Date != null)
            select con;
return query.ToList();
```

`Consultant.Goalcard` exposes all `GoalCards` of the `Consultant` as a queryable property. So you can perform queries on that, too. (This example assumes `Completed_Date` is nullable)

Note: Seeing that a `Consultant` can have several `GoalCard`s, you might want to rename the `Consultant`'s `GoalCard` navigation property to `GoalCards` (to make it clear there can be several).

Comment: And +1 to you (because why not?) for a different syntax and more elaborate answer! :)

Comment: Thanks for a great answer but Its not working for me since my List have to be List<Consultant> beacuse List<Int> is not working.

Comment: @RammtinAvar You said "What I want to do is to get all consultants ids", that was confusing me. Updated my answer, it now returns a `List<Consultant>`.

Answer (score 1):

Now assuming the `Complete_Date` is of type `DateTime?`, you could do it like that:

```
public IEnumerable<Consultant> GetConsultantIds()
{
     return db.Consultant.Where(c => c.GoalCard != null && c.GoalCard.Completed_Date.HasValue).Select(c => c.Id).AsEnumerable(); 
}
```

[EDIT]

Since `GoalCard` is a collection (misleading name :) ), you can do something like that to get the IDs of Consultants who have at least one completed date set on any of the cards:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetConsultantIds()
{
     return db.Consultant.Where(c => c.GoalCard != null && c.GoalCard.Any(card => card.Completed_Date.HasValue)).Select(c => c.Id).AsEnumerable(); 
}
```

That's for the list of IDs only, for the list of `Consultant` objects meeting the criteria:

```
public IEnumerable<Consultant> GetConsultantIds()
{
     return db.Consultant.Where(c => c.GoalCard != null && c.GoalCard.Any(card => card.Completed_Date.HasValue)).AsEnumerable(); 
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but GoalCard doesnt have any properties I cant type `c.GoalCard.Completed_date`

Comment: c.GoalCard is a collection so you need to query the collection

Comment: Ah, right, it changes the approach a bit. But should it return the IDs of the consultants who have ANY of the cards' dates set, all of the dates, some of the dates...? :)